# blender doesn't open when amd gpu driver is installed

Tags: gpu, installation

I know that Blender doesn't support AMD GPU's, but this isn't about that.

Blender was working just fine, but after I installed Catalyst, Blender won't open. Why?

My PC info:

- Win7
- Intel i7 3rd gen
- 6 gp ddr3
- AMD Radeon 7676m

Comment: If it was working before you might want to unistall the new dirver. Or maybe reinstalling Blender.

Comment: We need a lot more information than that to help you. What happens when you try to open Blender? Does Blender open at all? If so, when does it close? What version of Blender do you use(version number and 64-bit or 32-bit)? 64-bit or 32-bit version of Win7?